# Sum same property object by group

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a similar object structure.. my purpose is to sum the same property grouped by the same year(e.g 2016 --> importo1: 7500, importo2: 0, importo3: 0, importo4: 3000)

```
{
  index: 0,
  annoDelibera: 2020,
  importo1: 2500,
  importo2: 3000,
  importo3: 0,
  importo4: 2000
},
{
  index: 1,
  annoDelibera: 2019,
  importo1: 2500,
  importo2: 0,
  importo3: 0,
  importo4: 1000
},
{
  index: 2,
  annoDelibera: 2016,
  importo1: 2500,
  importo2: 0,
  importo3: 0,
  importo4: 1000
},
{
  index: 3,
  annoDelibera: 2016,
  importo1: 2500,
  importo2: 0,
  importo3: 0,
  importo4: 1000
},
{
  index: 4,
  annoDelibera: 2016,
  importo1: 2500,
  importo2: 0,
  importo3: 0,
  importo4: 1000
},
{
  index: 5,
  annoDelibera: 2015,
  importo1: 2500,
  importo2: 0,
  importo3: 0,
  importo4: 1000
},
{
  index: 6,
  annoDelibera: 2014,
  importo1: 2500,
  importo2: 0,
  importo3: 0,
  importo4: 1000
},
{
  index: 7,
  annoDelibera: 2014,
  importo1: 2500,
  importo2: 0,
  importo3: 0,
  importo4: 1000
}
```

What is the way to do this? My problem is that I try to sum, it's sum all the property by year and not the single properties

```
getSumGrouped(year) {
    let holder = {};
    let sum = =;
    for (let entry of this.config.fields) {
         for (let row of this.data) {
              if (holder.hasOwnProperty(row.annoDelibera) && holder.hasOwnProperty(entry.name)) {
                if(year == row.annoDelibera){
                  sum += Number(row[entry.name]);
                  holder[row.annoDelibera] = holder[row.annoDelibera] + sum;
                }

              } 
              else {
                if(year == row.annoDelibera){
                  sum += Number(row[entry.name]);
                  holder[row.annoDelibera] = sum;
                }
              }

            }
        fields.push({ style: { ...entry.style, ...entry.cellStyle }, value: holder[year] });
    }
}
```

I tried in this way, the **this.config.fields** gives me the same name property but come from another part. And **this.data** is the object structure data above.

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: The result for the search _"javascript group array of objects"_ should give you enough answers to achieve your goal.

Comment: in your attempt you're possibly *doing something wrong™* - by showing your attempt and having your mistake pointed out, you will learn a lot more

Comment: I edited the question with my attempt

Answer (score 1):

any approach would help but I'd solve it in a few steps:

```
const yearSum = yourObject.reduce((actuator, object) => {
  // if we have an index, do addition otherwise set current object as value
  if (actuator[object.annoDelibera]) {
    actuator[object.annoDelibera].importo1 += object.importo1;
    actuator[object.annoDelibera].importo2 += object.importo2
    actuator[object.annoDelibera].importo3 += object.importo3
    actuator[object.annoDelibera].importo4 += object.importo4
  } else {
    // strip index and year from values (can be omitted but is dirty if not as you'll have the index etc. for the total
    const {index, annoDelibera, ...rest} = object;
    actuator[object.annoDelibera] = rest;
  }
  return actuator; // return for next reduce loop
}, {});
```

In reduce you can do lots of things, the 4 lines setting importo1 can be set up in a way to allow any key and you could use the deconstruction pattern from the else statement to not sum up years and the index if it's a loop over the keys.

## Alternative

```
const yearSum = yourObject.reduce((actuator, object) => {
    // strip index and year from values (can be omitted but is dirty if not as you'll have the index etc. for the total
  const {index, annoDelibera, ...rest} = object;
  // if we have an index, do addition otherwise set current object as value
  if (actuator[object.annoDelibera]) {
    Object.keys(rest).forEach(key => {
      actuator[object.annoDelibera][key] += rest[key];
    }
  } else {
    actuator[object.annoDelibera] = rest;
  }
  return actuator; // return for next reduce loop
}, {});
```

The latter is more dynamic, but possibly not a requirement, I'd use clearer variables but I don't know what your object is about!

Answer (score 1):

You could find the same year and create a new object or update the wanted properties.

```js
var data = [{ index: 0, annoDelibera: 2020, importo1: 2500, importo2: 3000, importo3: 0, importo4: 2000 }, { index: 1, annoDelibera: 2019, importo1: 2500, importo2: 0, importo3: 0, importo4: 1000 }, { index: 2, annoDelibera: 2016, importo1: 2500, importo2: 0, importo3: 0, importo4: 1000 }, { index: 3, annoDelibera: 2016, importo1: 2500, importo2: 0, importo3: 0, importo4: 1000 }, { index: 4, annoDelibera: 2016, importo1: 2500, importo2: 0, importo3: 0, importo4: 1000 }, { index: 5, annoDelibera: 2015, importo1: 2500, importo2: 0, importo3: 0, importo4: 1000 }, { index: 6, annoDelibera: 2014, importo1: 2500, importo2: 0, importo3: 0, importo4: 1000 }, { index: 7, annoDelibera: 2014, importo1: 2500, importo2: 0, importo3: 0, importo4: 1000 }],
    grouped = data.reduce((r, { index, annoDelibera, ...o }) => {
        var temp = r.find(q => q.annoDelibera === annoDelibera);
        if (temp) Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => temp[k] += v);
        else r.push(temp = { annoDelibera, ...o });
        return r;
    }, []);
    

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the underscore library fuction:

_.groupBy

and later you can sum the items in each group. Reply if you it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the cleanest way but achieves what you've asked with no additional libraries.

```js
let data = [
{
  index: 0,
  annoDelibera: 2020,
  importo1: 2500,
  importo2: 3000,
  importo3: 0,
  importo4: 2000
},
{
  index: 1,
  annoDelibera: 2019,
  importo1: 2500,
  importo2: 0,
  importo3: 0,
  importo4: 1000
},
{
  index: 2,
  annoDelibera: 2016,
  importo1: 2500,
  importo2: 0,
  importo3: 0,
  importo4: 1000
},
{
  index: 3,
  annoDelibera: 2016,
  importo1: 2500,
  importo2: 0,
  importo3: 0,
  importo4: 1000
},
{
  index: 4,
  annoDelibera: 2016,
  importo1: 2500,
  importo2: 0,
  importo3: 0,
  importo4: 1000
},
{
  index: 5,
  annoDelibera: 2015,
  importo1: 2500,
  importo2: 0,
  importo3: 0,
  importo4: 1000
},
{
  index: 6,
  annoDelibera: 2014,
  importo1: 2500,
  importo2: 0,
  importo3: 0,
  importo4: 1000
},
{
  index: 7,
  annoDelibera: 2014,
  importo1: 2500,
  importo2: 0,
  importo3: 0,
  importo4: 1000
}
]

let byYear = {};

data.forEach(el => {
 if(!byYear[el.annoDelibera]) {
   byYear[el.annoDelibera]= {
     importo1: 0,
      importo2: 0,
      importo3: 0,
      importo4: 0
    };
  }
})

data.forEach(el => {
 byYear[el.annoDelibera].importo1 += el.importo1;
 byYear[el.annoDelibera].importo2 += el.importo2;
 byYear[el.annoDelibera].importo3 += el.importo3;
 byYear[el.annoDelibera].importo4 += el.importo4;
})

console.log(byYear);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
const data = [ { index: 0, annoDelibera: 2020, importo1: 2500, importo2: 3000, importo3: 0, importo4: 2000 }, { index: 1, annoDelibera: 2019, importo1: 2500, importo2: 0, importo3: 0, importo4: 1000 }, { index: 2, annoDelibera: 2016, importo1: 2500, importo2: 0, importo3: 0, importo4: 1000 }, { index: 3, annoDelibera: 2016, importo1: 2500, importo2: 0, importo3: 0, importo4: 1000 }, { index: 4, annoDelibera: 2016, importo1: 2500, importo2: 0, importo3: 0, importo4: 1000 }, { index: 5, annoDelibera: 2015, importo1: 2500, importo2: 0, importo3: 0, importo4: 1000 }, { index: 6, annoDelibera: 2014, importo1: 2500, importo2: 0, importo3: 0, importo4: 1000 }, { index: 7, annoDelibera: 2014, importo1: 2500, importo2: 0, importo3: 0, importo4: 1000 } ]

const result = data.reduce(function(res, obj) {
    if (!(obj.annoDelibera in res)){
        const { index, annoDelibera, ...r } = obj;
        res.arr.push(res[obj.annoDelibera] = r);
    }
    else {
        res[obj.annoDelibera].importo1 += obj.importo1;
        res[obj.annoDelibera].importo2 += obj.importo2;
        res[obj.annoDelibera].importo3 += obj.importo3;
        res[obj.annoDelibera].importo4 += obj.importo4;
    }
    return res;
}, {arr:[]})

console.log(result)
```